# Changing default file upload input

Tags: django

I'd like to add the following attribute to the  tag on the django file upload form as part of a progress bar implementation:

```
onchange="uploadFile()"
```

Do you know how I would be able to modify the default file upload input with this assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add the following to your form: `field.widget.attrs["onchange"]="uploadFile()"`

And include the javascript somewhere within the template being used.

Comment: Thanks for the help!